# Visual Studio C++ AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt() requires Admin privileges on my laptop to work

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc

I have a small VS2019/MFC C++ program that uses `AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt()` to write to a .ini file. This works fine on my Win 10 desktop, but on my Win 10 laptop it fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, unless I select *Run as Administrator*.

I know this function call is very out of date, but nevertheless it should still work. Any idea why it won't work on my laptop but does work on my very similarly configured PC? I'd rather not run the program with Admin privileges. UAC on both computers is set to the default setting.

Comment: What Windows 10 editions are in your PC and laptop?

Comment: This function is not really out of date, it provides a uniform interface to save data (usually settings or MRU files) to some configuration storage, which by default is the registry. If you have changed the default path and used an .INI file for example, this is normal, if the app is trying to save the file under a Program Files subfolder (although this should normally be mapped to a folder under C:\Usres\Username\.., in a transparent to the app way). Another possible cause may be attempting to store your data under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rather than HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry.

Comment: The PC is Win 10 Pro 21H1 64 bit, the laptop is Win 10 Home 21H1 64 bit.

The app is saving the data to c:\Windows\xxx.ini, and both computers successfully read the .ini file if it’s there. Ideally I’d like both computers to write it to c:\windows, but failing that how can I change the write location to the program’s directory? I want to avoid the registry and c:\users\username\... I inherited the app so I am not sure what was done to get WriteProfileInt() to write to c:\windows rather than the registry.

Comment: What is [CWinApp::m_pszProfileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#m_pszprofilename) set to? But really, you shouldn't be writing to C:\\Windows at all.

Comment: m_pszProfileName has a value of "xxx.ini". Still not sure why it works on one PC and not the other. Or how do I get it to write to the program's directory?

Comment: Set `m_pszProfileName` to point to the program's directory.

Comment: that seems to work, thank you (although I still don't know why my app can write to c:\windows on one PC and not the other).

Comment: Maybe because the user who runs the app does have rights there.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, in `InitInstance` you would make a call to `SetRegistryKey` to indicate where the setting data will be saved.